# Getting name by ID

Tags: c++

I've never bothered to `inline` any function, and I'm fairly unfamiliar with how it works. Would this function benefit from being `inline`d?

```
const char* GetNameByID(int ID)
{
  auto itor = std::find(Achievements.begin(),Achievements.end(),ID);
  if(itor != Achievements.end())
  {
      return (*itor).second->Name;
  }
  return "";
}
```

Comment: Why didn't you try and compare the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making a function inline means that any functions that call it will actually have the code embedded in the calling function by the compiler. Sometimes it results in a performance boost by removing overhead.

In older versions of C++ inline functions was more valuable, it is mostly a recommendation to the compiler now. Good optimizing compilers will inline for you.

There is not enough code here to tell if making this function inline will help, because the assistance in performance is in the calling function. If this function is called 1000 times in a loop, making it inline will help. If it's not called in a loop it will not really help.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the information. I suppose I'll inline it in this case. The for loop I use can potentially have up to 300 iterations, it seems inlining would indeed be beneficial. Also, I'll check out the how to ask page that way next time I have a question regarding code I can properly post.

Comment: @Jeff, on top of that, if the function is member function of the class, you can mark it as a const function. Be careful when inlining, if the function is too big it can get out of cache line, so next cycle will stall for some time before beginning.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks to both of you for the information. I'll do some perf analysis and decide whether or not inlining actually makes a difference.